# Refrence to a static file in javascript by html language

Tags: javascript, static, cytoscape.js

I try to use [cytoscape cxtmenu](https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js-cxtmenu). Here I can refer to the image file that symbolizes the context menu via the option "content" that interprets an HTML string. Usually I, refer to a static image-file in HTML via

```
<img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='images/file.svg') }}">
```

However, I running out of quote symbols as I would need three types of string-indicators

1. the overall HTML text needs to be a string
2. the src text needs to be a string
3. the filename needs to be a string

Does someone have an idea to solve this problem?

Lazloo

Answer (score 0):

You can use [template strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings) for this. They are really handy when working with strings that use variables.

A normal string looks like this:

`var string = "Lorem ipsum dolor";`

You can use single quotes just like above:

`var string = 'Lorem ipsum dolor;`

However, using template strings, you can do string concatination like this:

```
var img_file = 'images/file.svg';
var img_type = 'static';
var img_template = `<img src="{{ url_for('${img_type}', filename='${file}') }}">`
```